# Gradle configuration inheritance

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I have multiple dependencies inside a gradle file and I introduced a new build variant call "apple". But I don't want to copy and paste as the following.

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile "com.android:libraryA:1.0.0"    
    debugCompile "com.android:libraryB:1.0.0"    
    debugCompile "com.android:libraryC:1.0.0"    

    appleCompile "com.android:libraryA:1.0.0"    
    appleCompile "com.android:libraryB:1.0.0"    
    appleCompile "com.android:libraryC:1.0.0"    
}
```

Is there a way I can say `appleCompile` depends on `debugCompile`?

Comment: How are you defining `apple`? If you [use `initWith()`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types), that might copy over dependencies, if the dependencies are defined before you define the build type (i.e., `dependencies {}` appears before `android {}`). I haven't tried this, so I don't know if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was using apple.initwith(debug) and I tried with apple { initWith debug } as well and it only copies over the build variant config and not the depedencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a new configuration:

```
configurations {
    [debugCompile, appleCompile].each { it.extendsFrom commonCompile }
}
```

Now `commonCompile` configuration will apply dependencies for both `debug` and `apple` configurations, so you don't need to specify those twice.

```
dependencies {
    commonCompile "com.android:libraryA:1.0.0"    
    commonCompile "com.android:libraryB:1.0.0"    
    commonCompile "com.android:libraryC:1.0.0"    
}
```